Optimizing a While Loop for High-Precision Computation in Mathematica
Edit: Clarifying the Core Issue
i=x;
While[Abs[p1 - p2] >= p1 tol,
   p2 = p1;
   p1 += s *= i (mkn + i)/((k1 - i) (n1 - i));
   i--;
  ];

The core of my problem lies in optimizing the While loop above within the hypecdf function (defined below). This loop iteratively adds terms to compute the CDF until a specified convergence criterion is met. For large input values and high precision, this process becomes a significant bottleneck. I am specifically looking for ways to make this iterative process as efficient as possible within Mathematica.
Simply modifying the loop to
xvar=x;
mkni=mkn+x;
k1i=k1-x;
n1i=n1-x;

While[s >= p1 tol,
  p1 += s *= xvar mkni/(k1i n1i);
  xvar--; mkni--; k1i++; n1i++;
  ];


was enough to reduce the runtime of the example below by 1 second. I'm looking for further improvements.
Original post:
I'm working on a custom implementation of the cumulative distribution function (CDF) for the hypergeometric distribution in Mathematica.
The second function, which evaluates the CDF, involves a While loop to iteratively add probability terms until the difference between consecutive results is within a given tolerance. However, the loop is quite slow, especially for large input parameters. I need to optimize this process for better performance.
Implementation:
Here is  my code:
(* Log-based PDF for numerical stability *)
hypepdf[m_, n_, k_, x_] := 
 Module[{mchosenln, xfactln, nminxfactln, fac},
  
  mchosenln = 
   LogGamma[m + 1] - LogGamma[n + 1] - LogGamma[m - n + 1];
  xfactln = LogGamma[x + 1];
  nminxfactln = LogGamma[n - x + 1];
  fac = mchosenln + xfactln + nminxfactln;
  
  (LogGamma[k + 1] + LogGamma[m - k + 1] - LogGamma[k - x + 1] - 
     LogGamma[m - k - n + x + 1]) - fac
  ]
(* ----------------------------------------- *)

(* CDF function with While loop *)
hypecdf[m_, n_, k_, x_, tol_] := 
 Module[{s, p1, p2, mkn, k1, n1, i},
  
  s = Exp[hypepdf[m, n, k, x]];
  
  mkn = m - k - n;
  k1 = k + 1;
  n1 = n + 1;
  
  p1 = s;
  p2 = 1;
  i = x;


(*Major Bottleneck!!!*)

  While[Abs[p1 - p2] >= p1 tol,
   p2 = p1;
   p1 += s *= i (mkn + i)/((k1 - i) (n1 - i));
   i--;
  ];
  
(*Major Bottleneck!!!*)



  p1
 ]

(* ----------------------------------------- *)

Example Input:
Here is an example call to the hypecdf function:
m = 10^15.`64; (*Total population size*)
n = 1/10 m;    (*Sample size*)
x = 1/100 n;   (*Successes in sample*)
k = (1/100 + 1/10^7) m; (*Total successes in population*)
tol = 10^-16;  (*Tolerance for convergence*)

hypecdf[m, n, k, x, tol] // AbsoluteTiming

(*{7.49914, 1.588741685925020453368980761130047818186660444*10^-26}*)

Context:
The precision is set very high because of accumulation of large errors for such values. However, the While loop in my implementation is the bottleneck, and it becomes increasingly slow for larger values of m, n, and k.
Questions:

Are there ways to optimize or replace the While loop to improve performance?

Are there any numerical tricks or approximations that could speed up convergence without sacrificing accuracy?

Can the computation be vectorized or parallelized in Mathematica to avoid the sequential nature of the loop?


Any advice or references to optimized implementations for hypergeometric calculations would be greatly appreciated!

For large sample sizes and small success probability, can't you approximate the hypgergeometric distribution with a normal distribution with equal variance and mean:
NormalDistribution[mu, Sqrt[mu]] where mu is the mean of the hypergeometric distribution mu = n * k/m ?

^It looks like the mean and variance of the hypergeometric distribution aren't equal in this case (I'm assuming you're trying to approximate HypergeometricDistribution[n, k, m]) but a normal distribution with matched mean and variance NormalDistribution[n k /m, Sqrt[(k (-k + m) (m - n) n)/(-1 + m)]/m] seems to be a good approximation.

Thanks! Yes, thats true. But I need to evaluate the cdf and also need to specify its precision (as in how much could it possibly deviate from the output). This is crucial and I'm not really sure how the normal approximation can provide that ( I'm aware of some loose bounds on the tail but I'm looking for the tightest possible bounds ).

Maybe theres a way I can use this approximation as a guess and somehow use it to speed up the code. I'm not sure though

wp = 64; Block[{$MinPrecision = wp, $MaxPrecision = wp}, <code>]. Turns off error tracking in arb. prec. numbers, and speeds things up.
